# JavaScript: counter refreshment without reloading www

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a page with a list of questions. The counter is above each question. 
I need the counter to refresh after every click on the button (answer to the question), but without reloading the page.
Unfortunately, I can not hide the first counter after every click.

**Function "countDown" doesn't work.**
Can anyone help?

```
<div class="col quiz--header__time p-0">
    <b> 30 </b>  s.
</div>




        var cd = false;
        function countDown (time, reload) {
            var sec = time;
            if (reload) {
                if ($('.questionQ:visible').is(':not(:last-child)')) {
                    $('.quiz--header__time b').html(time);
                    clearInterval(cd);
                }
            }
            cd = setInterval(function () {
                sec--;

                $('.quiz--header__time b').html(sec);

                sec == 0 ? clearInterval(cd) : null;
            }, 1000);
        }




    function selfSubmit(time, obj) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            obj.parent().parent().find(':radio').click();
            countDown(30, true);
        }, time)
    }
```

Comment: *"click on the button"*: your code does not include the button, nor a click handler. Could you provide those?

Comment: If you want it only to refresh when you click just change the element in the click handler.